# I can not upload a file because of its large size using AJAX with Jquery in Asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, file, jquery-file-upload

I attach documents without problems with the following code:

```
$("#importarRut").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $("#ajax_loader").css("display", "");

                var fileUpload = $("#file_import").get(0);
                var files = fileUpload.files;
                var archivo = $("#file_import").val();

                var fileData = new FormData();

                for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                    fileData.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
                }

                if (files.length == 0) {
                    alert("Debe Adjuntar Excel");
                    return;
                }
                fileData.append("nameSheet", $("#idnombrehoja").val())
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Nombre/SaveImportacionRut/',
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: false, // Not to set any content header  
                    processData: false, // Not to process data  
                    data: fileData,
                    success: function (result) {
                        $("#ajax_loader").css("display", "none");

                        if (result.retornoJson == "1") {
                            alert('Excel Importado Correctamente');

                        } else {
                            alert("error: " + result.mensajeErrorJson + " linea:" + result.lineaErroJson);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (err) {
                        alert(err);
                    }
                });

            });
```

But when I upload a file of 102 MB, I get an error [object Object]. Which I conclude that, due to its large size, it does not allow it. In the webconfig I put this, to try to make it work:

```
<requestFiltering>
    <!--<requestLimits maxUrl="10999" maxQueryString="2097151" />-->
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="104857600" />
  </requestFiltering>

 <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="102400" executionTimeout="3600" />
```

But still, it does not work. Is there a possibility to enable or allow uploading files with large sizes? Or any solution?
regards

Comment: It is possible by using "partitioning" (breaking into smaller chunks and joining them again on server), you can found an example [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1034347/Upload-large-files-to-MVC-WebAPI-using-partitionin).

Comment: does the console show any error?